# Temperature Sensor issue in Google Home Automation via YAML Script Editor

Tags: yaml, google-home, google-smart-home

I'm trying to set up automation via the script editor, a new Google [feature](https://developers.home.google.com/automations/example-scripts). My goal is for the script to turn off the AC when the temperature, as detected by a sensor on my balcony, exceeds a certain value and the balcony door is open.

Here's the condition I wrote for the temperature sensor:

```yaml
condition:
    type: device.state.TemperatureControl
    state: temperatureAmbientCelsius
    greaterThan: 24
    device: WiFi Temperature & Humidity Sensor - Balcony
```

However, when I validate, I get the following error:

**[device.state.TemperatureControl] is an unknown type name.** Expected types: [and, or, not, time.between, device.state... (truncated for brevity)].

Interestingly, a similar condition works for humidity using `HumiditySetting`:

```yaml
condition:
    type: device.state.HumiditySetting 
    state: humidityAmbientPercent
    greaterThan: 55
    device: WiFi Temperature & Humidity Sensor - Balcony
```

It seems `TemperatureSetting` is reserved exclusively for thermostats. However, there's a note in the documentation:

> Sensors that report data covered by another trait should use that trait with the queryOnly* attribute for that trait set to true. For example, temperature sensors should use the TemperatureControl trait with the queryOnlyTemperatureControl attribute set to true.

I'm unsure how to set this attribute in the script editor. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you guys tried the following by any chance ,

condition:
    type: device.state.TemperatureSetting
    state: thermostatTemperatureAmbient
    greaterThan: 24
    device: WiFi Temperature & Humidity Sensor - Balcony ?

Comment: yes, I tried it. if I select device.state.TemperatureSetting then I can only set a thermostat (AC) as a device, however, I need to make it work for a temperature sensor

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue and I don't think there's a solution right now.  I'm hoping someone just needs to update a code validator somewhere.  device.state.TemperatureControl seems to be the right struct.  It appears to be the same as the one described here: https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits/temperaturecontrol.  

"Trait for devices (other than thermostats) that support controlling temperature, either within or around the device.

This differs from the TemperatureSetting trait, which is specifically for thermostat-style controls."

Comment: Here's a Google Nest Community discussion.  I've linked directly to the most relevant comment.  https://www.googlenestcommunity.com/t5/Home-Automation/Let-s-discuss-creating-powerful-automations-with-our-new-script-editor/m-p/469421/highlight/true#M21063

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, in my case, I use a ZigBee network-connected temperature and humidity sensor. Within Google Home, I've set up the following activation commands for the air conditioner:

```
automations:
  starters:
    - type: device.state.TemperatureControl
      device: Sensor - Bedroom
      state: temperatureAmbient
      greaterThanOrEqualTo: 30C
      suppressFor: 40min
```

If the temperature read by the sensor is greater than or equal to 30 degrees Celsius, it then executes the activation command.

```
condition:
    type: and
    conditions:
      - type: device.state.TemperatureControl
        device: Sensor - Bedroom
        state: temperatureAmbient
        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 30C
      - type: time.between
        after: 13:30
        before: 18:00
        weekdays:
          - MON
          - TUE
          - WED
          - THU
          - FRI
```

In the conditional command, I've set it to check if the temperature is greater than or equal to 30 degrees and if it's within the time range of 13:30 to 18:00 on weekdays.

For the humidifier, I basically used the same approach, but I used commands based on the humidity percentage.

For the activation of the routine:

```
automations:
  starters:
    - type: device.state.HumiditySetting
      state: humidityAmbientPercent
      lessThanOrEqualTo: 30
      device: Sensor - Bedroom
      suppressFor: 40min
```

For the execution condition of the routine:

```
 condition:
    type: and
    conditions:
      - type: device.state.HumiditySetting
        device: Sensor - Bedroom
        state: humidityAmbientPercent
        lessThanOrEqualTo: 30

      - type: time.between
        after: 13:30
        before: 18:00
        weekdays:
          - MON
          - TUE
          - WED
          - THU
          - FRI
```

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to use my Govee temperature sensors (3 x H5100 connected to the H5151 hub) with the help of the Google Home Script Editor! I was about to return them because Google Home wouldn't let me use them as a trigger, but this Google Labs feature saved the day.

Here is my solution to turn off a smart outlet when the temperature gets too hot:

```
metadata:
  name: Turn Off Heat
  description: If temp is too high, turn off heat for pepper garden

automations:
  starters:
    - type: device.state.TemperatureControl # Activate based on the temperature value of the sensor.
      state: temperatureAmbient
      greaterThanOrEqualTo: 70F
      device: Pepper Temp (1) - Backyard # --- Temperature Sensor
      suppressFor: 10min # Wait 10 minutes before checking the starter script again

  condition: # If smart outlet isn't already on, there's really no need to send command
    type: device.state.OnOff
    state: on
    is: true
    device: Peppers - Backyard # --- Smart Outlet

  actions:
    - type: device.command.OnOff # Turn off the smart outlet
      on: false
      devices: Peppers - Backyard # --- Smart Outlet

    - type: assistant.command.Broadcast # Broadcast to my Google Home Mini for a fun audio confirmation :D
      message: Those are some HOT PEPPERS!
```

One thing I figured out the hard way is that "condition:" is not plural and therefore does not expect a list, so it does not require a "- " before the "type:" key.

Answer (score 0):

To be interpreted as a temperature your value needs an "F" or "C" after it.  Otherwise it doesn't interpret it as a temperature.